# Get index at which names of vector match supplied names

Tags: r

Is there a `which` analog for character extraction?

Say `x <- c("low" = -10, "high" = 10)`. It's great that `x[c("high", "low")]` returns `c(10, -10)`; for what I'm trying to do, I want the corresponding matched indices, namely `c(2L, 1L)`.

This seems like it'd be pretty basic, but `which` is not vectorized and `?extract` offers no help that I saw.

A solution which seems like it should be overkill is:

```
> sapply(c("high", "low"), function(y) which(names(x) == y))
high  low 
   2    1
```

Is there no easier way to do this?

Comment: Would `match(names(x), c("high", "low"))` do it?

Comment: @RichardScriven indeed. `%in%` had passed my mind, I'm glad I read `?match` and finally see that `%in% `is just more-specific `match`. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by RichardScriven, this has a simple `base` solution:

```
match(names(x), c("high", "low"))
```

See `?match`.